# npm start gives: Cannot find module 'typings-core' error

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I've been literally battling with typescript & angular2 the whole day today, since I was unable to start the development server for my app. After hours of frustration followed by lots of googling, I finally managed to get rid of all the errors but one:

```
node_modules/typings/dist/support/cli.d.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'typings-core'.
```

Could anyone provide a solution for this? (couldn't find anything online).

Thanks,
Piotr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got away with the error by adding the code below to tsconfig.json

```
    "skipLibCheck": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm cache clean;
npm update typings;
npm i typings -s;
npm i typings -g;
```

If they still fail: `npm remove typings;` and try those commands again.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I got the same error:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ typings/
npm install
typings install
```